# Code in functions.php appearing on front-end and dashboard

Tags: functions, dashboard, front-end, code

My WordPress theme is so minimalistic, that it didn't even have a `functions.php` file. But I wanted to use Google Fonts in my site. I read on elsewhere (www.designbombs.com/add-google-fonts-wordpress) that the recommended method to embed Google Fonts is to use `wp_enqueue_style()` function. So, I needed a `functions.php` file and I created one.

Then I included this code in there, as per instructions in the blog post.

```
function custom_add_google_fonts() { 
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abhaya+Libre:300,400,400i', false ); 
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_add_google_fonts' );
```

Now my site is embedded with the particular font I need and I can use it with no problem, but there is something wrong.

I can see the code I entered in my new `functions.php` file, from my Dashboard and also from front end.

[image: Back-end look]

[image: Front-end look]

I will really appreciate if anybody can help me on how to hide this code from showing up on my website.

Comment: Make sure your code is in `php` tags. Only problem I can think of is your code is out side `php` tag. Hence it's considered as HTML and printed directly.

Comment: @AniruddhaGawade - that was very stupid of me to be that careless. Thanks :) it worked out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your sccrenshot you have added your PHP code without PHP tags. PHP codes should be in inside `<?php` and `?>`.

And if you have used it as PHP Short Tag (`<?`) make sure that to set `short_open_tag=On`
in php.ini